# how to use $ function on two events simultaniously in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a text box and image button, I want to search the content entered in the text box (both enter on text box) and click on the search image(icon) should work..

I tried this :

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

    $('.customSearchButton').on("click","img", function (e) {

       var search = $("#txtSearch").val();         
       var searchEncoded = encodeURIComponent(search);

       window.location = "/Search.aspx?name=" + searchEncoded;

     });
});
```

My Html is :

```
 <li class="customTopNavSearch">
                                            <input type="text" id="txtSearch" />
                                            <a href="#" class="customSearchButton">
                                                <img src="search-button.png" alt="Search" />
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Warp the common code in a function. Bind the function as click event handler for image and on the click of enter call the method.

```
function myEventHandler(){
   var search = $("#txtSearch").val();         
   var searchEncoded = encodeURIComponent(search);

   window.location = "/Search.aspx?name=" + searchEncoded;
}

$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('.customSearchButton').on("click","img", myEventHandler);
    $("#txtSearch").on("keyup",function (e) {
        //If Enter is pressed call the method
        if(e.which == 13){
            myEventHandler();
        }
     });
});
```

[event.which](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/)

> For key or mouse events, this property indicates the specific key or button that was pressed.

Comment: I don't know but I think `$('.customSearchButton').on("click","img",` isn't right in this context. Yet hard to know without any markup provided.

Comment: @empiric, You summed it up. However You should not doubt OP intelligence, He will have a fair idea how to use it

Comment: Enter is not working in the search box. I am using it in sharepoint html master page.  This snippet is not working $("#txtSearch").on ("keyup", function(event){
    if(event.which == 13){
 myEventHandler();
        alert('test')
    }
});

Answer (score 4):

What you are using is called [event-delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). This assumes your `img`-element is a descendant of your `.customSearchButton`-element.
If you want to bind a event on multiple elements you can simply seperate them with a comma:

```
function redirect(){
    var search = $("#txtSearch").val();         
    var searchEncoded = encodeURIComponent(search);

   window.location = "/Search.aspx?name=" + searchEncoded;
}

$('.customSearchButton, img').on("click keypress", function (e) {

       if (e.which == 13 && $(e.target).is('input')) {
           redirect();
       } else if($(e.target).is('img')){
           redirect();
       }

 });
```

This snippet will trigger when hitting enter on the `input` or clicking on the `img`.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvrazfnp/)**

According of what you are trying to achive it would be indeed more practically to define two different event-handlers and invoke a secondary function.
Note: If you want to have access to the element which triggers the event inside the function you can simply pass the `$(this)`-object as a parameter.

**Reference**

[.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

[.which](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/)

Comment: click on image and enter in text box....user can choose any one..  it is like a search box.

Answer (score 2):

Extract the functionality out:

```
function PerformSearch()
{
    var search = $("#txtSearch").val();
    var searchEncoded = encodeURIComponent(search);
    window.location = "/Search.aspx?name=" + searchEncoded;
}
```

Then you can bind it to whatever you want:

```
  $('#txtSearch').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        PerformSearch();
    }
  });

  $('.customSearchButton').on("click","img", PeformSearch);
```

NOTE: `e.which` holds the value you'll use to evaluate which key was pressed (i.e. which key press invoked the handler). All key presses will invoke the keypress handler, but it is the enter key you wish to check for (which has the value 13).